# How can I be able animate value change in Shape?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am updating my shape with a variable called count which is a Int, I implemented the needed code for applying the animation for Shape even explicitly used the transition, but i am not able to animate my shape, looking to solve and learn the issue in my code.

Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b) in SwiftUI-macOS

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var count: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {

            RectangleShape(count: count)
                .fill()
            
            Button("update") {
                if (count >= 4) { count = 1 }
                else { count += 1 }
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity)
        .animation(.default, value: count)
 
    }
}



struct RectangleShape: Shape {
    
    var count: Int

    var animatableData: Int {
        get { count }
        set { count = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        return Path { path in

            switch count {
            case 2:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
            case 3:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
            case 4:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
            default:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
            }

        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is going into the right direction, just some aspects:

The `animatableData` var `count` should be `Double` (not Int) as SwiftUI can only animate by changing from the start value to the end value in incremental steps, which it couldn't do with `Int`.

Based on this incremental change of `count` SwiftUI is calling your Shape over and over again. So your shape has to be able to draw the "in between" steps by reacting on `count`. I did include code for that based on my understanding of what you might want to achieve.

Lastly I commented out things you won't need.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var count: Double = 0 // use Double, start with 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {

            RectangleShape(count: count)
                .fill()
            
            Button("update") {
                    if (count >= 4) { count = 0 } // reset to 0
                    else { count += 1 }
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top)
//        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity)
        .animation(.default, value: count)
 
    }
}



struct RectangleShape: Shape {
    
    var count: Double // use Double

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { count }
        set { count = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        return Path { path in

            switch count {
            case 0...1:
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0 * count, height: rect.height/2.0))
            case 1...2:
//                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0 * (count-1), height: rect.height/2.0 ))
            case 2...3:
//                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0 * (count-2)))
            case 3...4:
//                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0, height: rect.height/2.0))
                path.addRect(CGRect(x: rect.midX - rect.width/2.0 * (count-3), y: rect.midY,
                                    width: rect.width/2.0 * (count-3), height: rect.height/2.0))
            default: do {}
//                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            }

        }
    }
        
}
```